# Data sets to predict/classify using machine learning

Tags: data-request, medical

I'm looking for a data set that I can use to predict/classify using machine learning methods like SVM, trees, logistic regression, etc.

I would love something related to health/medicine, so I could use methods to detect early-stage diseases for example. But other areas are good too.

Comment: please see the UCI Machine Learning Repository, where you can filter by what type of ML you would like to do, and also what type of data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the Pima Indians Diabetes [dataset](https://data.world/data-society/pima-indians-diabetes-database)? This dataset could be quite a good fit for the methods of analysis you mentioned.

Comment: I saw that one and it's perfect. However, that data is very used already. I'm looking for a data set that I can use in my masters thesis, so I dont know if that one is good for that.

Comment: Also, I don't mind finding a good reference (with good reputation) and doing what they've done and do even more. Do you know any high reputation journal/group that done something with this data set? Found a lot online but they are not that good

Comment: I'm afraid health/medicine is not my area, so I unfortunately wouldn't be in a position to advise on journals or other datasets.